# .htaccess mod_rewrite web.com/text to web.com/index.php?page=text

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect (mod_rewrite) the URL that user enters to another.
User enters:

www.example.com/text

And the URL to display should be:

www.example.com/index.php?test

I have this .htaccess file, but it does not work (I get 404 error):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Where am I wrong?
Thanks everyone

Comment: Yes, it does load fine.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Well good point, it does not generates 500 error

Comment: Well then it needs to be enabled from httpd config

Comment: I guess I have to contact the technical support of the webhosting to enable it?

Comment: Ok, thank You, that was good point, I did not have this idea. :)